# Sort text file with last field

Tags: linux, shell, sorting, unix

I have text file as shown below:

```
cc_1 ( AB GND ) capacitor c=1.72728p
cc_2 ( AB VIN ) capacitor c=26.9013p
cc_3 ( AB H_SNS ) capacitor c=15.2554p
cc_4 ( AB L_SNS ) capacitor c=2.89517p
cc_5 ( AB VREG ) capacitor c=23.7678f
cc_6 ( AB VIN ) capacitor c=1.34133f
```

I want to sort this file by last column. Last column is a mix of number and a character(e.g. 1.72728p). So I want to sort by last character first and then by the number. So the output should look like this:

```
cc_2 ( AB VIN ) capacitor c=26.9013p
cc_3 ( AB H_SNS ) capacitor c=15.2554p
cc_4 ( AB L_SNS ) capacitor c=2.89517p
cc_1 ( AB GND ) capacitor c=1.72728p
cc_5 ( AB VREG ) capacitor c=23.7678f
cc_6 ( AB VIN ) capacitor c=1.34133f
```

Any suggestions on how to achieve this output?

Comment: Do all numbers have the same number of characters? Ex. `1.34133` and `23.7678` have both 7 characters. Then you can just define smart KEYDEF with [sort](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sort.1.html). Otherwise, preprocess the input with `sed` and extract number and character to separate the fields, `sort` the file and remove the fields you extracted using `cut`.

Comment: No all numbers do not have same number of characters. Some of them have 5,6 and 8 as well. Could you give an example how to extract it using sed?

Comment: Like backreference the number (ie. `[0-9\.]` numbers and a dot) and the letter and just output them separated by space: `sed 's/=\([0-9\.]*\)\([a-z]\)$/& \1 \2/`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input_file sed 's/^.* c=\([0-9\.]*\)\(.\)$/\2 \1 &/' |
xargs printf "%s %030.10f %s %s %s %s %s %s %s\n" |
sort -k1.1r -k2.2n |
cut -d' ' -f3-
```

- First the input goes through sed. I extrect the float number and the letter behind it. The output becomes `<letter> <float numbe> <rest of the line`
- Then I had troubles* with `--generic-sort` with `sort`. `--generic-sort` is a gnu sort extensions anyway.
- So I decided to format the float number, to have at least 20 leading zeros and at least 10 numbers behind the comma. I use simple `xargs` with `printf`. If `30.10` is not enough precision for you, you can always increase it (like `100.50`).
- Then I sort. I reverse sort using the `<letter>` column and then I numeric sort using the number.
- I then remove first two fields.

Tested with:

```
cat <<EOF >file
cc_1 ( AB GND ) capacitor c=1.72728p
cc_2 ( AB VIN ) capacitor c=26.9013p
cc_3 ( AB H_SNS ) capacitor c=15.2554p
cc_4 ( AB L_SNS ) capacitor c=2.89517p
cc_5 ( AB VREG ) capacitor c=23.7678f
cc_6 ( AB VIN ) capacitor c=1.34133f
cc_6 ( AB VIN ) capacitor c=1.44133f
cc_6 ( AB VIN ) capacitor c=1.24133f
cc_6 ( AB VIN ) capacitor c=12.24133f
cc_6 ( AB VIN ) capacitor c=11.24133f
cc_6 ( AB VIN ) capacitor c=13.24133f
cc_6 ( AB VIN ) capacitor c=13.24133001f
cc_6 ( AB VIN ) capacitor c=13.24133003f
cc_6 ( AB VIN ) capacitor c=13.24133002f
EOF

<file sed 's/^.* c=\([0-9\.]*\)\(.\)$/\2 \1 &/' |
xargs printf "%s %030.10f %s %s %s %s %s %s %s\n" |
sort -k1.1r -k2.2n |
cut -d' ' -f3-
```

will output:

```
cc_2 ( AB VIN ) capacitor c=26.9013p
cc_3 ( AB H_SNS ) capacitor c=15.2554p
cc_4 ( AB L_SNS ) capacitor c=2.89517p
cc_1 ( AB GND ) capacitor c=1.72728p
cc_5 ( AB VREG ) capacitor c=23.7678f
cc_6 ( AB VIN ) capacitor c=13.24133003f
cc_6 ( AB VIN ) capacitor c=13.24133002f
cc_6 ( AB VIN ) capacitor c=13.24133001f
cc_6 ( AB VIN ) capacitor c=13.24133f
cc_6 ( AB VIN ) capacitor c=12.24133f
cc_6 ( AB VIN ) capacitor c=11.24133f
cc_6 ( AB VIN ) capacitor c=1.44133f
cc_6 ( AB VIN ) capacitor c=1.34133f
cc_6 ( AB VIN ) capacitor c=1.24133f
```

- Side note: I think theoretically the following should work:

```
<file sed 's/^.* c=\([0-9\.]*\)\(.\)$/\2 \1 &/' |
sort -s -k1.1r -k2.2g
```

however it does not and doesn't properly sort the `15` and `1` and `2` (sorts numeric, not as floats, thus dot `.` makes everything invalid (showing `head -n4`, note how `2.8` is greater then `15.2`):

```
p 26.9013 cc_2 ( AB VIN ) capacitor c=26.9013p
p 2.89517 cc_4 ( AB L_SNS ) capacitor c=2.89517p
p 15.2554 cc_3 ( AB H_SNS ) capacitor c=15.2554p
p 1.72728 cc_1 ( AB GND ) capacitor c=1.72728p
```

Answer (score 0):

If the data has the format shown, specifically, only one equals sign (`=`), then it is quite easy to do:

```
sort -t= -r -n -k2,2 datafile |\
rev | sort -s -r -k1.1,1.1 | rev
```

- the first sort splits on `=` and then sorts numerically
- then we reverse the line so that the final character is easy to find
- then we do a stable sort on that single character (stable means sort only changes line order when it needs to (so the previous sort isn't lost)
- finally undo the reversal

Answer (score 0):

```
cat input.txt | awk -F"c=" '{print $NF}' |
while read line ; do echo ${line: -1:1}${line:0:-1} ; done |
sort -k1.1,1.1 -r -k1.2,1.3nr |
while read line ; do grep ${line:1}${line:0:1} input.txt; 
done > result.txt
```

First of all got the column needed for sort with awk by delimeter "c=";

Replace the last character to the beginning for sorting;

Sorted by first character, than by others; (reverse sorting as you wanted);

Extracted lines from input file to the result file by the sorted column.